# Nested layout inside CardView overlaps parent end

Tags: android, android-layout

I have no idea how this can happen, but I have a ConstraintLayout with a CardView inside. Inside said CardView is a LinearLayout. That LinearLayout overlaps the parent on the end. Check the screenshot for more info. If I remove the android:layout_margin from the cardView, the inner layout looks good again, but adding margin to start seems to just push the entire layout to and over the end of the parent. It doesnt matter what sort of layout is used inside the CardView. The issue affects them all.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite">
        ..

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/wakeuptimer_status_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/md_keylines"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                .....
```

[image]

Comment: Why you want to use LinearLayout when you can map whole thing inside it using Constraint-layout

Comment: Old habits. Also, using a ConstraintLayout inside the CardView results in the same issue. Anyway, It seems the problem is the margins in the card view. If I remove the android:layout_margin from the cardView, the inner layout looks good again. Weird.

Comment: Seems like the `CardView` needs to set the `start_to_start_of` and `end_to_end_of` as `parent`, meaning the ConstraintLayout. But just looking at the top of the view, it also seems like there is room for making this xml more simpler just by re-organizing a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the Linearlayout height to **match-parent** instead of wrap_content. With wrap_content you aren't restricting the size of the Linearlayout view to the size of the CardView.

```
           <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
```